# How to efficiently remove leading rows containing only 0 as value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe and the first rows have only zeros as value.
I would like to remove those rows.

So, denoting df my dataframe and ['a', 'b', 'c'] its columns. I tried the following code.

```
df[(df[['a', 'b', 'c']] != 0).all(axis=1)]
```

But it will also turn the following dataframe :

```
a b c
0 0 0
0 0 0
1 0 0
0 0 0
2 3 5
4 5 6
0 0 0
1 1 1
```

Into this one :

```
a b c
1 0 0
2 3 5
4 5 6
1 1 1
```

That's not what I want. I just want to focus on leading rows. So, I would like to have :

```
a b c
1 0 0
0 0 0
2 3 5
4 5 6 
0 0 0
1 1 1
```

It would be great to have a simple and efficient solution using pandas functions. Thanks

Comment: Try `df = df.iloc[2:]`

Comment: Hi thanks for commenting. I don't want a static solution. It works for this simple example. I know a way involving for loops to check the first row that is not equal to 0, and then apply .iloc, but I would like a better solution using pandas.

Comment: @kakrotto, you mean you want to remove rows with 0's if they are consecutive ?

Comment: Not only @BharathM, I would like to remove the first consecutive rows with 0's.

Comment: How about `df[df.sum(1).cumsum().ne(0)]` ..?

Comment: @ChrisA doesn't work, seems to do the same job as ```df[(df != 0).any(axis=1)]```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General solution working if all `0` rows in data - first use `cummsum` for cumualtive sum and then test any `True`s per rows:

```
df1 = df[(df[['a', 'b', 'c']] != 0).cumsum().any(1)]
print (df1)
   a  b  c
2  1  0  0
3  0  0  0
4  2  3  5
5  4  5  6
6  0  0  0
7  1  1  1
```

Solution if at least one non `0` row in data - get first value of non `0` rows with [`Series.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html):

```
df1 = df.iloc[(df[['a', 'b', 'c']] != 0).any(axis=1).idxmax():]
print (df1)
   a  b  c
2  1  0  0
3  0  0  0
4  2  3  5
5  4  5  6
6  0  0  0
7  1  1  1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that finds the first row that is *not* all zeros and then selects all from that point on. Should solve the problem you are describing:

```
ix_first_valid = df[(df != 0).any(axis=1)].index[0]
df[ix_first_valid:]
```